# How can I find the passphrase in the keychain after adding it with ssh-add -K

Tags: macos, keychain, ssh

I have added my ssh passphrase to my keychain with `ssh-add -K` option but I cannot seem to find it in the keychain. I have looked at login keychain and icloud keychain. I used the command line application `security` without luck. I even looked at every single entry in the login keychain to see which applications are allowed to read in case I stumble on ssh-agent. Any tips for finding it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the security command line tool does not work with icloud keychain but with an independent keychain. I can find my ssh key using keychain access (the desktop app) and searching for the filename or the file path.

Comment: Seems like it was there but I had to restart keychain to see it. Thanks for pointing at the right direction.